# How to script permissions for all logins/users/tables/schemas

Tags: sql-server, permissions, scripting

Over the years, I have used countless scripts and applications to generate all permissions for SQL Server databases. I have used both paid and free tools. I feel that not one of them seems to be accurate in every instance. I am simply looking for a way to generate all permissions for a given database along with confidence that the script is correct and able to be used after a backup/restore from another instance. Does anyone have a method they have confidence in and use regularly

Answer (score 5):

I have a couple of stored procedures that I wrote and use on a regular basis.

- [sp_SrvPermissions](http://sqlstudies.com/free-scripts/sp_srvpermissions/)
- [sp_DBPermissions](http://sqlstudies.com/free-scripts/sp_dbpermissions/)

They each have three outputs.

- `Principals` : A list of the database/server principals and associated info including create/drop scripts.
- `Role membership` : A list of what roles each database/server principal belongs to along with add/drop scripts.
- `Permissions` : A list of individual permissions (EXECUTE, INSERT, UPDATE, CONNECT etc) for each database/server principal.

Obviously the Srv sp is for the Server principals and the DB sp is for the database level principals.  The DB sp also has an 'All' option for the database name.  With this option it runs through and pulls all permissions for all databases.

Note: This was originally intended as a research tool so there are a fair number of options that will let you parse down your data.  Just roles, everything but roles, just a specific principal name etc.

Comment: Great couple of scripts! I use them a lot too, really handy pair of sp's. And been able to transfer password's and SID's, thumbs up for you Kenneth

Comment: Good scripts Kenneth! sp_DBPermissions seems to return everything I need with the exception of "VIEW DEFINITION" that is granted to users on a database. No records are returned for those.

Comment: Odd.  That should show up.  I would a) confirm that under the database they are explicitly granted VIEW DEFINITION (not through a role, AD group etc) and then double check the system views. sys.database_permissions joined to sys.database_principals.  If it's not in those views it won't show up in the SPs.

Comment: @KennethFisher What led you to write your own vs. use SMO?  I am trying to figure out how to script out Database-Level permissions right now with SMO, and not sure it is possible.

Comment: @JohnZabroski I'm good at t-sql and understand the system views a lot better than I understand the SMO objects. Not to mention the system views tend to change slower so my scripts run over a wider variety of versions.  I've thought about re-writing as Powershell as an exercise but haven't gotten around to it yet.

Answer (score 2):

`sp_help_revlogin`

See: [How to transfer logins and passwords between instances of SQL Server on MSDN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/918992)

Worked reasonably well for me this past summer.

Comment: sp_help_revlogin only transfers server principal information.  It doesn't transfer anything at a database level.  Very useful for what it does though.

Comment: if you move/migrate to a new server you should not need to script every db permission over. They will come along with the migrated db.

Comment: Very true. Unless you happen to be migrating between SDLC levels.  Say copying over dev with test but then you want to put the dev permissions back the way they were.

Comment: @KennethFisher you usually have roles for that.

Comment: @spaghettidba Don't the permissions for the roles change between dev & test? Or prod & test?  Or at least the members?  It's handy to have that type of thing scripted out.

Comment: @KennethFisher sure, it's nice to have them scripted out. For me it's usually just a matter of adding/removing members to/from roles.